# PHP save increment variable from loop

Tags: php

How can I save last increment inside variable?

and it is that possible?

```
abstract class myClass()
{
   private $increment = 0;

   public function run()
   {
     foreach ( .... ){
       $this->increment++;
```

Now every time it is call the loop, the increment variable start from zero, that because is a new instance of class.

There is a way for continue from last increment variable?

Any suggestion?

**EDIT**: class is abstract

thanks

Comment: What if you made the variable static ?

Comment: You intend to increment the value for _all_ instances of the class? That could be done with `private static $increment = 0;` and `static::$increment++` but that has other implications. Should each instance start from the existing increment but continue it's own changes independently? http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php#language.oop.static.properties

Comment: make a global variable in app

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I can not access to the property static inside method, the method is not static.

Comment: @GabrieleCarbonai You actually can. Depends how you are accessing it.

Comment: https://3v4l.org/iLCXB

Comment: Have you considered storing the value in Database. Sure you can store them in global variables, but if you want to again increment from the last place *after* restart, storing in DB is the only good way.

Comment: Can we see how you're using the function/class?

Comment: I am using in the same way like @AbraCadaver shared 3v4l.org/iLCXB

Comment: I just discovered the class is abstract, can be that?